# Book: Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming, 2nd Edn; Chapter 3 - Simulating Robot using ROS & Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am facing many problems. I am trying to learn ROS from the book they have supported officially but unfortunately, I am facing problem. I tried to simulate the model given in Chapter 2 of the same book and faced problem which is already reported [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/242044/book-mastering-ros-for-robotics-programming-2nd-edn-chapter-2-working-with-3d-robot-modeling-in-ros/).

Now in the sequel, I am trying to learn Gazebo to simulate 7DOF robot given in that chapter given [online](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros) but when I run it, I get this error.

```
-- Could not find the required component 'controller_manager'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.

CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "controller_manager" with any of the following names:

    controller_managerConfig.cmake
    controller_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "controller_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "controller_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "controller_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  chapter_3_codes/diff_wheeled_robot_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 under ROS Kinetic. I have also tried to run under Virtual Machine for Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo and got this error.

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package): 

Could not find a package configuration file provided by "joy" with any of
  the following names:
joyConfig.cmake
joy-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "joy" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "joy_DIR"
  to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "joy" provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  chapter_3_codes/diff_wheeled_robot_control/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'joy'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
```

Edit 1: September 6, 2016

> Are you sure you ran the rosdep commands properly? Were there any errors? If I look at chapter_3_codes/diff_wheeled_robot_control/package.xml for instance, I definitely see a <build_depend>controller_manager</build_depend> and a run_depend, which should have resulted in rosdep installing ros-$distro-controller-manager for you.

I followed these official tutorials ([link](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu)) to thoroughly check the `rosdep.` . I also checked the installed packages by using command

```
apt-cache search ros-kinetic
```

and I did see these packages available in installation

```
ros-kinetic-control-msgs - control_msgs contains base messages and actions useful for controlling robots.
ros-kinetic-control-toolbox - The control toolbox contains modules that are useful across all controllers. 
ros-kinetic-controller-interface - Interface base class for controllers
ros-kinetic-controller-manager - The controller manager.
ros-kinetic-controller-manager-msgs - Messages and services for the controller manager.
ros-kinetic-controller-manager-tests - controller_manager_tests
```

So, I guess the necessary packages are still there. But still I tried to run as per your instructions to run this command.

```
sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
```

and simply got this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-rosinstall is already the newest version (0.7.8-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I guess, ROS is somehow not finding the path because I have noticed that it is also saying me something like this.

```
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "controller_manager" with any of the following names:

    controller_managerConfig.cmake
    controller_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "controller_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "controller_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "controller_manager" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.
```

Edit 2: September 6, 2016
I have just followed one more thing here from the tutorial ([link](http://wiki.ros.org/Installation/Source))
and I tried running this command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y`

and then I got this error. I guess, the problem lies here.

```
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
amr_robots_description: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [urdf_tools]
```

The discussion has gone so long and boring. I end up here. I am so thankful to you for taking care. May you get the reward for helping me out. I cannot give you anything at the moment but I shall definitely help someone else whenever it is possible as you helped me.

Edit 2: September 07, 2016.

Yes, the problem is finally solved. I ran this command.

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r
```

and it returned me that something was missing and needs to be installed. After installation, code is finally being compiled. I am really very very thankful to gvghoorn for all his care and help. Thank you so much. I can never say thanks enough for your such a kind help. I have no words for that. I wish, I could be like you. Thanks brother.

Really thankful to you gvdhoorn.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242778/book:-mastering-ros-for-robotics-programming,-2nd-edn;-chapter-3---simulating-robot-using-ros-&-gazebo/) by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-08-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-31**:\

> [..] the book they have supported officially [..]

Who is 'they' here, exactly? Afaict, the book is written by an author not affiliated with the OSRF?

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-09-01**:
This book is officially recommended by ROS for the beginners who wants to understand ROS step by step in 3-4 months.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-01**:
Please update your question with the exact commands you used, in which order and the resulting output of all of them. Especially the command line and output of `rosdep`.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-09-05**:\

> This book is officially recommended by ROS for the beginners

Can we see where this takes place? I do not think ROS (assuming you meant OSRF) recommends any book `officially` IMO.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-07**:
Good to hear you got it to work. For the future: if you download someone's code, always first run a `rosdep install ..` to make sure you have all dependencies installed. Assuming the author of the pkgs did his work, that should be enough.

And no need to thank me; this is why ROS Answers exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing packages. The errors you get tell you that *at least* `controller_manager` is not installed on your machine.

Most efficient way to fix this:

```
source /opt/ros/$DISTRO/setup.bash
rosdep update
rosdep install --from-paths /path/to/your/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src
```

Then follow the prompts.

I'd be surprised if the book didn't tell you about this though, it's a basic step to get someone else's sources working in your workspace.

---

Edit:

> I am using Ubuntu 16.04 under ROS Kinetic. I have also tried to run it under Ubuntu 14.04 and ROS Indigo.

The `controller_manager` package has been released on both [Indigo](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=controller_manager) and [Kinetic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=controller_manager), so it should install on both. I cannot guarantee that all the other dependencies of the *Mastering ROS for Robotics Programming* book are available on Kinetic though. `rosdep` will tell you when it can't find something.

---

Edit2:

> I tried but still the same. It is not working. Same error and same thing.

Are you sure you ran the `rosdep` commands properly? Were there any errors? If I look at [chapter_3_codes/diff_wheeled_robot_control/package.xml](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/blob/d2861487dd012b5fdcf232f949e6f51fadc780a0/chapter_3_codes/diff_wheeled_robot_control/package.xml#L43) for instance, I definitely see a `<build_depend>controller_manager</build_depend>` and a `run_depend`, which should have resulted in `rosdep` installing `ros-$distro-controller-manager` for you.

Did it install *any* new packages?

---

Edit3: just noticed that [chapter_3_codes/seven_dof_arm_gazebo/package.xml](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/blob/d2861487dd012b5fdcf232f949e6f51fadc780a0/chapter_3_codes/seven_dof_arm_gazebo/package.xml#L43-L52) does not list `controller_manager` as either a run or a build depend. But it also doesn't use it. So I'm wondering what kind of output you got from `rosdep`: does it say "All system dependencies have been satisified"?

---

Edit4:

> I also checked the installed packages by using command

> ```
> apt-cache search ros-kinetic
> ```

> and I did see these packages available in installation

Afaik, `apt-cache` searches in *all available packages*, not just those installed on your machine. See what `dpkg -l | grep controller-manager` returns.

> But still I tried to run as per your instructions to run this command.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall
> ```

I don't think I asked you to run that command. I asked you to run `rosdep update` and `rosdep install ..` (see top of answer).

> I tried running this command `rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y`

> and then I got this error. I guess, the problem lies here.

> ```
> ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
> ```

```
to system dependencies:
amr_robots_description: Cannot locate rosdep definition for [urdf_tools]
```

That was indeed the command I asked you to run at the very beginning. The fact that it is failing here could mean that it doesn't continue to install all the other dependencies.

Can you please try the following command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro kinetic -y -r
```

**notice the `-r`** that makes `rosdep` continue in case it can't find/install something.

Please run that command, and add the output of it to your original question.

We're particularly interested in any output mentioning the `controller_manager` package, or any of its dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-09-01**:
Thank you so much gvdhoorn for your answer. I have tried the solution you proposed but it is not working. Please suggest me something. I am so stuck up here.